# Change the background Color of Div using Angular Js Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change the background color of Div with Directive.Here is my code: .

```
.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
              elem.bind('click', function() {
              elem.html("<p>This is the new content</p>");
              elem.css("background-color", "black");
              elem.css("color", "white");
              elem.css("border", "5px solid red");
          });
      elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
      elem.css('cursor', ' ');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
AngularApp.directive('ngToBlack', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                elem.css("background-color", "black");
                elem.css("color", "white");
                elem.css("border", "5px solid red");
            });
            elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
                elem.css('cursor', ' ');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

call it as:

```
<h3 ng-to-black>Change background, color and border</h3>
```